# accessibility of truncated view in Android

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

what should be the Talkback behavior on the truncated view. In one application talkback is reading entire message along with the view more button. Functionality is like that when using click on more detail additional detail what expanded and more details button become the less details, problem is that when focus went to truncated messages  talkback is reading  entire message which could be of one paragraph to too many  paragraphs or so on. Ideally it should read only display message however functionality  has been designed in such a way that entire text is coming in application and through UI it has been hide.
My questions are
1 is there a way to read only that part of text which has been displayed even whole message has been provided 
2 if not possible above approach, who'd be the length of characters talkback should read and stop as i can do so 
I also keep this thing in mind that length in truncated view can be increase or decrease depending on screen xiae 
Thanks
Anubhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the view's content description to be the truncated version of the text. Update the content description when the truncated text changes, ex. if the view size changes.

```
someView.setContentDescription(truncatedText);
```